# Необходимо изменить цвет строки DataGrid в коде

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Искал подобные вопросы, но не совсем понимаю всё же, как это можно сделать.
У меня по таблице `DataGrid` проходит цикл и производит какие-то расчеты на основе данных элементов `DataGrid.Items`, и в зависимости от результата необходимо окрасить некоторые строки соответствующих элементов. Получается я должен как-то программно изменить свойство `Background` некоторых строк.

P.s. Я сделал, как изменить цвет ячейки в зависимости от значения

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Status}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Status, Converter= {StaticResource NameToBrushConverter} }"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>


public class NameToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Robot.status input = (Robot.status)value;
        switch (input)
        {
            case Robot.status.waitSignal:
                return Brushes.LightGray;
            case Robot.status.inPosition:
                return Brushes.LimeGreen;
            case Robot.status.waitDeal:
                return Brushes.Yellow;
            default:
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге и решил эту проблему, оказывается, всё просто
В XAML :

```
                     <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="waitSignal">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="inPosition">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="waitDeal">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```